# comparing two tables and removing ones that match

Tags: sql

I have two tables. MembID is the only column returned for each. The MembID can be in both tables but I would like to remove the ones that are in both from the results.

[image]

I'd like the final return to be 456 and 789 from Table A.

I've tried:

```
select distinct a.membid
from a
 left join b on a.membid = b.membid
and b.num <> 1
```

it does not return any results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below

```
select distinct a.membid
from a
 left join b on a.membid = b.membid
where b.membid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

> The MembID can be in both tables but I would like to remove the ones that are in both from the results.

If you want members in only one table, here is one method:

```
select memberid
from ((select memberid, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b from a
      ) union all
      (select memberid, 0, 1 from b
      )
     ) ab
group by memberid
having max(in_a) + max(in_b) = 0;
```

Note that this version allows duplicates within each table.

In databases that support set-based operators, you can also do:

```
(select memberid from a union
 select memberid from b
) except -- sometimes this is minus
(select memberid from a intersect
 select memberid from b
);
```

EDIT:

Your description of the problem doesn't match your data.  You seem to want the members in `a` that are not in `b`.  One method elaborates on the first:

```
select memberid
from ((select memberid, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b from a
      ) union all
      (select memberid, 0, 1 from b
      )
     ) ab
group by memberid
having max(in_a) + max(in_b) = 0;
```

Or the second:

```
select memberid from a
except  -- or minus
select memberid from b
```

However, I would typically do:

```
select distinct memberid
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.memberid = a.memberid);
```